# How to patch CVE-2022-26373 for Ubuntu 20.04 gcp-5.13 and gcp-5.15?

Tags: kernel, security

Is there any patch/upgrade available for CVE-2022-26373, specifically for Ubuntu 20.04 gcp-5.13 and gcp-5.15?
From https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-26373:

| Package | Status |
| --- | --- |
| linux-gcp-5.13 | Ignored (superseded by linux-gcp-5.15) |
| linux-gcp-5.15 | Pending (5.15.0-1021.28~20.04.1) |
| linux-gcp-5.3 | Does not exist |

What does that mean "Doesn't exist" for gcp-5.3? Can we upgrade the kernel version from 5.13/5.15 to 5.3 to remediate CVE-2022-26373?

Answer (score 1):

Be calm. Do not panic.

Review the information you provided: `linux-gcp-5.15 | Pending (5.15.0-1021.28~20.04.1)`. That means a patched package will be released soon.

"*What does that mean "Doesn't exist" for gcp-5.3?*" It means that older 5.3 did not have this vulnerability at all.

"*Can we upgrade the kernel version from 5.13/5.15 to 5.3 to remediate CVE-2022-26373?*" That would be a downgrade (not an upgrade), and suggests panic. Don't panic.

Advice: Use 5.15. Await the patched package.

Advice: Since this vulnerability affects local access only, ensure you have adequate local access security to deter/deny an attacker. That's always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04, you should upgrade to `linux-gcp-5.15` since this is the latest release.